# java - Fix an invalid Duration

Tags: java, sed, duration

We get xml with invalid duration, like PT10HMS (note lack of numbers before M and S).  I have handled this by reading the file and fixing by iterating the duration string character by character and inserting 0 between 2 letters that are side by side (except between P and T).  I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution maybe using a regex with sed or anything else?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more correct to delete the letters that haven’t got a number in front of them (again except P and T)? Not that it makes any difference in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea for a Java solution here (sure `sed` can be used too).

```
    String incorrectDuration = "PT10HMS";
    String dur = incorrectDuration.replaceAll("(?<!\\d+)[HMS]", "0$0");
```

This produces

```
PT10H0M0S
```

Personally I would prefer deleting the letters that do not have a number in front of them:

```
    String dur = incorrectDuration.replaceAll("(?<!\\d+)[HMS]", "");
```

Now I get

```
PT10H
```

In both cases `Duration.parse(dur)` works and gives the expected result.

`(?<!\\d+)` is a negative lookbehind: with this the regex only matches if the H, M or S is not preceded by a string of digits.

**Edit:** I am probably overdoing it in the following. I was just curious how I could produce my preferred string also in the case where you have got for example `PTHMS` as you mentioned in the comment. For production code you will probably want to stick with the simpler solution above.

```
    String durationString = "PTHMS";
    // if no digits, insert 0 before last letter
    if (! durationString.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
        durationString = durationString.replaceFirst("(?=[HMS]$)", "0");
    }
    // then delete letters that do not have a digit before them
    durationString = durationString.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)[HMS]", "");
```

This produces

```
PT0S
```

`(?=[HMS]$)` is a lookahead. It matches the empty string but only if this empty string is followed by either H, M or S and then the end of the string. So replacing this empty string with `0` gives us `PTHM0S`. Confident that there is now at least one digit in the string, we can proceed to delete letters that don’t have a digit before them.

It still wouldn’t work if you had just `PT`. As I understand, this doesn’t happen. If it did, you would prefer for example `durationString = PT0S;` inside the `if` statement instead.

Comment: I liked the getting rid of letters with no numbers but that didn't work because for a value PTHMS it left PT which was invalid.  I suppose I could test for this and replace it but the regex for inserting 0's worked perfectly so I'm using it  Thanks!!  One day I'm going to have to do some reading on regular expressions.

Comment: Good point! I think I thought about this possibility, but then forgot to write about it in the answer, sorry. @kevin